# Unique popup window using window.open in an iframe

Tags: firefox, javascript

I have an iFrame with a window open(`url`,`uniqueID`,`windowparams`).
The iFrame is located on a single page app and hosted in another server.
Everytime I refresh or change the page then return to the IFrame page, then try to initiate the same `window.open`. Instead of refreshing the already opened window, it creates an instance of the same window. Upon checking the `window.name` of each popup, it returns the same `uniqueID` as its `window name`. If the url is set blank it behaves as expected. But when a url is set, it creates a new instance of the window.

- Do iFrame `window.open` behave like that when destroyed?
- I tried running the iFrame source locally and the window open behaves properly even after refreshing.
- I tried in IE, Firefox, and Chrome, and it returned the same behaviour.

#### UPDATE:

Mike successfully fixed the behavior for Webkit browsers by added sandbox properties for the iFrame source. Now the `window.open` method works as intended and not creating new instances of the same window of the same `window.name`.

However, Mike still has no luck with Firefox. If someone could give a work around for this, it would be much appreciated.

The Webkit browser behaviour for an iFrame with sanboxed properties in the video below.

> See that the parent, even when refreshed still can detect that there is an already opened popup of the same name.
>   https://youtu.be/z5_xXRjY8Ow

The Firefox behaviour for an iFrame with sanboxed properties in the video below.

> When the parent window is refreshed, the browser could not detect the already opened popup and creates another instance of the pop up with the same `window.name`.
>   https://youtu.be/uHaDveW1Sd0

Is there a workaround to make Firefox behave like Webkit browsers?